# Spring Boot in Docker container behind Nginx reverse proxy not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, nginx

I have a problem with a Spring Boot application running inside docker container, which is running behind nginx reverse proxy.

To check that docker and nginx are working correctly I've tried folloging, which worked as expected:

```
docker run -d -p 9001:80 nginx:alpine
```

My nginx config looks like

```
server {
 server_name xyz.com;
 listen 80;
 location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
 }
}
```

Now I'm able to reach the nginx welcome page from the internet via xyz.com and let's assume the server's IP address is 123.123.1.1, via http://123.123.1.1:9001 as expected.
Also on the server itself, I get the welcome page via

```
curl http://localhost:9001
```

I think that shows, that docker and nginx are working as expected.

Let's go further down towards my problem.

Now I have build a simple Spring Boot application, which is bind to address 0.0.0.0 and port 9001. (Of course I have stopped the nginx container before going on...)
After the maven build, I have started the application with

```
java -jar app.jar
```

After it started up, I can reach it on the server with

```
curl http://localhost:9001
```

and from the internet via xyz.com and http://123.123.1.1:9001 - everything fine as expected.

Now, I've stopped the application und build a Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
COPY target/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","/app.jar"]
```

First building the image with `docker build -t app:latest .` and afterwards run the container with `docker run -p 9001:9001 -d app:latest`. So far so good, the container starts up - fine.

And here is the problem:
I'm not able to reach the application neither via xyz.com nor on the server witch `curl http://localhost:9001`! But via http://123.123.1.1:9001 it worked!

I've tried to check it inside the container `docker exec -it [container] sh` and afterwards `# wget localhost:9001` worked fine. `# netstat -tulpn` on the container itself brings following

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
```

Also on the server `$ netstat -tulpn` shows the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      607173/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN      607180/docker-proxy
```

Maybe something with iptables, but not sure what.
Hopefully somebody out there has an idea to help me.
Thanks in advance!

**Update**
When I used port 80 inside the container (The Spring Boot application listen now on port 80 instead of 9001) - magically it works! Tried port 8080 inside the container also - this didn't work!
Looks like a port problem, maybe someone can explain where the problem is?!

Comment: What does it say when you run `curl http://localhost:9001`?

Comment: Then nothing happens! It is running into timeout?! `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer `

Comment: That happens when, in the container, there is no process listening on the port that is exposed… But that’s clearly not the problem here.  
Looks like a bug to me somewhere… Maybe Docker is broken? A Linux Kernel bug?
Did you try using another image, like `openjdk:11-jre-slim`?

Comment: Tried two other images `openjdk:11` and as mentioned by @auktis `openjdk:11-jre-slim` - both the same behavior that I can only reach port 9001 by public ip address of the server, but not with localhost...

Comment: And if you expose only on localhost: `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9001:9001 -d app:latest`?